# Minimal Warp webserver example

Tags: haskell, haskell-warp

I want to create a website using the [Warp](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/warp) webserver in Haskell.

As I'm a Haskell beginner, examples like [this one](https://langnostic.blogspot.com/2013/02/wai-without-yesod-simple-example-of_10.html) are too complex for me.

Can anyone show me a simple, minimal example of how to use *Warp*?

*Note:* This question intentionally shows no research effort as it was answered Q&A-style.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Here's a minimal *Hello World* application using Warp 3.0+. Run it, then navigate to `http://localhost:3000`. This example will show `Hello world`.

In order to keep this example minimal, URL paths are not handled at all (the same content is delivered for any path). For a slightly longer example incorporating URL path handling, see [the Haskell Wiki](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Web/Servers#Warp)

```haskell
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Network.Wai (responseLBS, Application)
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp (run)
import Network.HTTP.Types (status200)
import Network.HTTP.Types.Header (hContentType)

main = do
  let port = 3000
  putStrLn $ "Listening on port " <> show port
  run port app

app :: Application
app _req f =
  f $ responseLBS status200 [(hContentType, "text/plain")] "Hello world!"
```

Comment: Please explain the downvote, just downvoting this won't make the post any better!

Comment: Note that the first line including `OverloadedString` is significant, because it allows the conversion of normal strings to `ByteString`s.  Otherwise this example would need to be modified to explicitly convert strings like `"text/plain"` and `"Hello world!"` to `ByteString`s via `Blaze.ByteString.Builder.Char8` and/or `Data.ByteString.Char8`.