# Listen on specific host using warp

Tags: haskell, haskell-warp

When running a [warp](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/warp) application using [`run`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/warp-2.1.2.1/docs/Network-Wai-Handler-Warp.html#v%3arun), it listens on all IP adresses.

For security reasons, I want to listen on `localhost` only, handling remote access using a reverse proxy.

How do I need to call `run` to only listen on a specific host/IP?

*Note:* This question intentionally shows no research effort as it was answered Q&A-Style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The currently accepted answer got broken by changes to conduit and/or warp. Warp no longer exports a `Host` constructor. But you don't need it, because the `HostPreference` type supports the OverloadedStrings extension, so you can just use a string directly.

This example also eliminates the deprecation warnings by switching to `setPort` and `setHost`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Network.Wai (responseLBS)
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp
import Network.HTTP.Types (status200)
import Network.HTTP.Types.Header (hContentType)

main = do
    let port = 3000
    putStrLn $ "Listening on port " ++ show port
    let settings = setPort port $ setHost "127.0.0.1" defaultSettings
    runSettings settings app

app req = return $
    responseLBS status200 [(hContentType, "text/plain")] "Hello world!"
```

Comment: Thanks for updating to the latest API! I actually updated my own code a long time ago but forgot to update my answer accordingly. I'll mark your answer as accepted!

Comment: You can also use `fromString`. Strangely, `read` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

`run` itself can't do that. you need to use [`runSettings`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/warp-2.1.2.1/docs/Network-Wai-Handler-Warp.html#v:runSettings):

The [`Settings`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/warp-2.1.2.1/docs/Network-Wai-Handler-Warp.html#t:Settings) parameter you want to pass it contains the information about the hosts it listens on.

The relevant type here is [`HostPreference`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/warp-2.1.2.1/docs/Network-Wai-Handler-Warp.html#t:HostPreference). Although it allows you to specify different wildcards, including `IPv6Only`, we'll use the `Host` constructor here.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22620295/2597135), I'll show a minimal example to listen on localhost only.

Note that accessors like `settingsHost` are marked deprecated, but the official documentation for warp 2.1.2.1 still shows an example using `settingsTimeout` [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/warp-2.1.2.1/docs/Network-Wai-Handler-Warp.html#t:Settings).

```haskell
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Network.Wai (responseLBS)
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp
import Network.HTTP.Types (status200)
import Network.HTTP.Types.Header (hContentType)

main = do
    let port = 3000
    putStrLn $ "Listening on port " ++ show port
    let settings = defaultSettings { settingsPort = port,
                                     settingsHost = Host "127.0.0.1" }
    runSettings settings app

app req = return $
    responseLBS status200 [(hContentType, "text/plain")] "Hello world!"
```

Comment: Please explain the downvote, just downvoting this won't make the post any better!

Comment: As far as I can tell, `Network.Wai.Handler.Warp` doesn't export the `Host` constructor, at least not anymore.